# Is there a Windows app for accessing my cell phone's GPS chip for Google Maps?

Tags: mobile-phone, gps, google-maps, tethering

I'm travelling by train using my notebook with a Sony Ericsson cellphone connected as a modem. The phone has a GPS chip for using Google Maps.

Is there a Windows app which can connect to the phone's GPS chip and display my current position in real-time?

Comment: i don't think the phone's GPS chip is really there for using Google Maps... i think Google Maps using that GPS data is a helpful side-effect.